# 2 Tables: A and B - change a column's value in table A based on a new inserment or update in Table B

Tags: java, spring

I have a stock table and a table that stores the sales made. What should I do so that, when a new sale is made or an old one is updated, the quantity of the product in the stock table decreases based on the purchased quantity? In my HTML form to add a new sale, I have made a select from which you can select the product's ID. Can I take that id and take the products quantity into the next select which you can choose the quantity from? Also I'm working with Spring/Thymeleaf in Java.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "sales")
public class Sales {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String date;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "representative_id")
    private Representative representative;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private Client client;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stock_id")
    private Stock stock;

    private int quantity;
    
    //////////////////

@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String product;

    private String color;

    private String size;

    private double price;

    private int quantity;
```

```html
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Add a New Sale</h1>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/sales/saveSale}" th:object ="${sale}"  method="POST">

        <h7>Representative ID</h7>
        <select th:field="*{representative.id}" required >
            <option value="">Choose...</option>
            <option  th:each="representative: ${representative}" th:value="${representative.id}" th:text="${representative.id}" ></option>
        </select><hr>

        <h7>Date</h7>
        <input type="date" th:field="*{date}" class="form-control mb-4 col-4" required><hr>

        <h7>Client ID</h7>
        <select th:field="*{client.id}" required >
            <option value="">Choose...</option>
            <option  th:each="client: ${client}" th:value="${client.id}" th:text="${client.id}" ></option>
        </select><hr>

        <h7>Stock ID</h7>
        <select th:field="*{stock.id}" required >
            <option value="">Choose...</option>
            <option  th:each="stock: ${stock}" th:value="${stock.id}" th:text="${stock.id}" ></option>
        </select>
        <hr>

        <h7>Quantity</h7>
            <input type="number" min="1" th:field="*{quantity}"  class="form-control mb-4 col-4" required>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info col-2"> Insert </button>
    </form>
    <a th:href = "@{/sales}"> Go Back</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Hibernate, an interesting solution would be to use the `@PostPersist` and `@PostUpdate` methods:

In your `Sales` Class, add the methods:

```
@PostPersist
private void decreaseQuantityAfterPersist(){
    //...
    //Here, you should calculate the quantity to be decreased and call a @Service
}

@PostUpdate
private void decreaseQuantityAfterUpdate(){
    //...
    //Calculate the quantity to be decreased after the update. If the code for the @PostPersist
    //and for the @PostUpdate are the same, you just need to annotate one method with both annotations
}
```

Intuitively, every time a new `Sales` object is inserted in the database, the `decreaseQuantityAfterPersist` will be executed. Every time a `Sales` object is edited, the `decreaseQuantityAfterUpdate` will be executed. These methods are both executed after the database transacts the change, therefore, when inside these methods, you will have access to all the other fields (eg. the quantity) and objects that act as foreign keys (which means you'll have full access to the correct Representative, Client and Stock objects with their id's, if needed).

Comment: By call a @Service do you mean calling a method from my Service Class?

Comment: Yes, considering that you will need to update the value of the quantity of your `Stock` in the database.

Comment: Okay, but how to call the Service method? I have tried autowiring the service but that does not work, should i just make a new instance of the service inside of the decreaseQuantityAfterPersist() method?

Comment: I have added the code below in my Sale Class, but now i'm getting these errors:java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at sap.project.data.enteties.Sales.decreaseQuantityAfterPersist(Sales.java:130) ~[classes/:na]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]




      `@Autowired
       @Transient
       private StockServiceImpl stockService;
       @PostPersist
       private void decreaseQuantityAfterPersist(){
       stockService.updateQuantity(stock.getId(),quantity);
       }`

Comment: SprinBoot considers an Entity as an ordinary Object, therefore, you can't obtain instances for `@Service`s from there so easily. Read [Injecting Spring Beans into Unmanaged Objects](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-bean-into-unmanaged-objects)

Comment: Strangely enough it still gives me the same error.